# How to run different code in django based on heroku deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to setup a python/django project. I work locally in win7 and would like to push to heroku. Ideally I would work in a virtualized environment to match local and deployment environments but sometimes its not possible. what is the most efficient way to run

```
if (in heroku):
    do this
else:
   do that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an environment variable. In Heroku's case it looks like:

```
heroku config:set WORKING_ENVIRONMENT=HEROKU
```

And then check this variable in your code:

```
if os.environ['WORKING_ENVIRONMENT'] == 'HEROKU':
    pass
else:
    pass
```